# Giving value to arrays with user inputt

Tags: arrays, vba, inputbox

I have to make a code where the user inputs 10 grades using input boxes. The input is to be displayed in a list box and then an average grade is calculated with the inputs. I have the code to get the input and display them in the list box but how to do I make it so the values inserted are given to the array. The array is predefined as- intGrades(1 To 10). ex. the first input value is given to intGrades(1) and so on until the last value input is given to intGrades(10). I am new to coding so I am sorry if this is an easy question.

```
 Private Sub cmdAddGrades_Click()
     Dim intGrades(1 To 10) As Integer
     Dim intText As Integer
     Dim intCounter As Integer
      
      Do
      intText = InputBox("Enter a Grade:")
      intCounter = intCounter + 1
      If intText > 100 Then
      MsgBox "Too High, nice try"
      Unload Me
      ElseIf intText < 0 Then
      MsgBox "Too Low, nice try"
      Unload Me
      End If
      lstGrades.AddItem intText
      Loop Until intCounter = 10
 end sub
```

Comment: You mean like `intGrades(intCounter) = somevalue`? And better declare arrays always starting from 0, this way you wont later stuck into off-by-one kind of problems.

Comment: - Arvo    It is kinda hard ti explain. So the inputbox pops up 10 times for each input. And I want each input to be placed with an index in the array, so the first input will be given to the (1) position in the array. So if they type 25 for the first inputbox then intGrades(1) = 25. And I need that to happen for each input

Comment: And how my simple statement does not work for you?